# Setting event handler in a callback

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to setup an eventhandler after a ajax request returns successfully.
setup_chat() is what sets the eventhandler, and setup_chat() works correctly unless I call it as a callback function. Like so:

```
$('#create_game_btn').on('click', function(){
        $.ajax({
        url: 'games/new',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'text',
        error: function (xhr, status) {
          alert(status);
        },
        success: function (result) {
        alert("Callback done!");
        window.location.replace('games/start');
        setup_chat(2);

    }
});

});
```

Comment: I guess you are saying that this works. Could you also add what doesn't work ?

Comment: You immediately open a new page, games/start. You then try to execute javascript on the current page. That will not work.

Comment: @panta82 Why won't it work? Is there a function like onLoad for redirections. Thanks.

Comment: @Chintan my bad. I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You need to add this function setup_chat on the games/start page. Call it on load. You cant add javascript from your current page to be executed on a new page.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
    window.location.replace('games/start');
    setup_chat(2);
```

This will load a whole new page. All the javascript on the current page will be unloaded. `setup_chat(2)` call will have no effect.

In order to "fix" this, you need to call this code after the new page is loaded. You can't do this from your ajax callback.

For example, at the bottom of your `<body>` tag on the page that loads from `games/start`:

```
<script>
    setup_chat(2);
</script>
```

The other option is not to load a new page at all.

I can't help you any further than this. You might need to learn more about web development before you can tackle this.